# how to call a function that returns a stream inside a loop

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

i have a function with the following definition:

```
validate(item: ValidationItem): Observable<ValidationResult>{}
```

i need to write a function that would iterate through an array of ValidationItem and, once it receives the ValidationResult from the validation of all of them, execute some logic before returning a result. how would i go about doing something like that?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking ... do you have example inputs and outputs? Is the existing non-array function working?

Comment: yes, the non-array function works. a ValidationItem is something that needs to be validated through database access and a ValidationResult is essentially the server's reply to the ValidationItem

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of the working function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `forkJoin`

> forkJoin(...args, selector : function): Observable When all
>   observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.

```
function validate(item: ValidationItem): Observable<ValidationResult>

const items: ValidationItem[] = [];
const validationResults$ = items.map(item => validate(item));

forkJoin(validationResults$).pipe(
 /* "execute some logic before returning a result" */
)
```

Comment: i didnt use this exact same syntax but this is the right approach. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are probably searching for the [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) operator. It returns an observable that emits exactly once, namely when all parameter observables are completed:

```
const x = of(1, 2, 3);
const y = of(10, 20, 30);
const z = of(100, 200, 300);

const items = [x, y, z];

/* yields [3, 30, 300] */
forkJoin([x, y, z]).subscribe(results => console.log(results));
```

You can also try this code online at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lpc7px).